# Recommend the best cluster framework to use in Java

Tags: java, frameworks, cluster-computing

I need  to share some jobs between different machines in a network. Is there any suitable framework in Java to use.

In more details: consider you have some app, receiving some input data. As a result if its analysis you code decides to make some operations but based on some logic it can not afford to execute all necessary operations because of a lack of computational resources. So, it has to distribute the rest of task's parts among other machines. So, is there any framework which allows me to make such a distribution ? (I suppose it must provide some functions on registering machines, tasks creation, gathering the result...)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried java JGroups its simple to create channel  register nodes and transfer data to multiple nodes. 
but you have to write your own code to divide your task and aggregate.

Comment: Ho, I've not! Going to investigate that. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Jgroups sounds interesting is it sill maintained? Has it a reasonable community?

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is one such framework developed by Apache.

Comment: A've also been given advice to try ZooKepper - does it fit my needs ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for **[Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/)** an opensource clustering framework developed in pure java.

See [ExecutorService](http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#ExecutorService) section.

ExecutorService in hazel cast allows distributed execution of tasks.

Comment: A've also been given advice to try ZooKepper - does it fit my needs ?